# Android: Re-opening formerly opened URI (OwnCloud storage)

Tags: android, uri, owncloud

With ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, I can open files that are stored in my OwnCloud storage.

uri.toString() gives, for example: content://org.owncloud.documents/document/157

How can I open that "file" directly without choosing it after browsing to the appropriate directory and selecting it?

The error message is: Exception: Permission Denial: opening provider com.owncloud.android.presentation.documentsprovider.DocumentsStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{...} (pid=9920, uid=10413) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

Comment: First you say that you can open such files. Then you ask how you can open them directly. I do not understand what you want.

Comment: So did you [persist your access to the Uri](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions)?

Comment: Thank you ianhanniballake for the link, that solved my problem.